# Flurl Array Encoding

Tags: c#, flurl

I am attempting to post some data that includes a string array to an endpoint but receiving an error "Invalid array"

Doing this:

```
   .PostUrlEncodedAsync(new
     {
        amount = 1000,
        allowed_source_types = new[] { "card_present" },
        capture_method = "manual",
        currency = "usd"
     });
```

Results in this being posted:

amount=1000&**allowed_source_types=card_present**&capture_method=manual&currency=usd

The API vendor complains that the array that I posted is invalid.  When I do this:

```
    .PostUrlEncodedAsync(
             "amount=1000&allowed_source_types[]=card_present&capture_method=manual&currency=usd"
    );
```

Results in this being posted:

amount=1000&**allowed_source_types[]=card_present**&capture_method=manual&currency=usd

The API vendor is happy and I get the expected results.

Question: Is this a bug and should the allowed_source_types parameter have included the **[ ]** as initially detailed [here](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/195)?

Comment: In URL parlance, using `allowed_source_types[]=card_present` sets the value of the parameter named `allowed_source_types[]` to the single value `card_present` -- which is not the same as setting a parameter named `allowed_source_types`. An API can certainly use parameter names with `[]` in them (if properly encoded when sent over to the server) but it's not standard. It would not be correct for Flurl to add the `[]` without being asked to. The tricky bit of course is that you can't specify a property with `[]` in the name in C#, so an alternate mechanism is needed for that.

Comment: It's also worth checking if the API accepts the "standard" way of passing multi-valued parameters (`a=val1&a=val2&a=val3`) or if it uses something else there too (`a[]=val1,val2,val3`). The latter is also not something a generic library should do without being asked to. (Having said that, the standards don't actually say anything about multi-valued parameters, but the first way is the one browsers have used since the days of yore, hence "standard". APIs may well have different ideas.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Everything in your comments is exactly right, and what you describe as most "standard" is exactly what Flurl does, so I'd invite you to put that in an answer. `PostUrlEncodedAsync` gives special treatment to dictionaries, which is the best way I can think of to get the `[]` added.

Comment: @ToddMenier: I have no experience whatsoever using Flurl, so there's probably a better answer possible to someone who does. Specifically, the "proper" way to call this API in a Flurl-accepted way would be good (posting a literal query string you made yourself is always possible, of course, but that's the least attractive way).

Comment: @JeroenMostert - Thanks for the details.  Learned something for sure.  Had tried passing the equivalent of a=val1&a=val2&a=val3 and the API gave an 'invalid array' error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a bug. As mentioned in the comments, there's no standard for URL-encoding a collection, but doing it like this:

```
x[]=1,2,3
```

is a lot less common than doing it like this:

```
x=1&x=2&x=3
```

The latter is [how Flurl has implemented it](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/15).

The trouble with doing it the way the API requires is that `[]` are not valid in a C# identifier, so the typical object notation won't work. But Flurl gives special treatment to `Dictionary` objects, so your best bet is to do it like this:

```
.PostUrlEncodedAsync(new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    ["amount"] = 1000,
    ["allowed_source_types[]"] = "card_present", // or string.Join(",", allowedSourceTypes)
    ["capture_method"] = "manual",
    ["currency"] = "usd"
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the details.  Passing the dictionary worked as expected.  And thank you for giving us Flurl.  You've made the C# world a better place!

Answer (score 0):

I had a simmilar issue where I passed an array of string to get request using flurl. First I joined each member of array with comma **","** but when sending the request the comma was being encoded to **"%2"** so flurl when setting query parameter has this option **"isEnabled"** that allows you to set it true and when it is true it skips the **encoding**.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetGroupUsersAsync(string realm, string[] groupIds)
    {
        string groupIdsStr = string.Join(",", groupIds);

        return await GetBaseUrl(realm)
            .AppendPathSegment($"/realms/{realm}/custom-endpoint/users/get")
            .SetQueryParam("groupIds", groupIdsStr, true)
            .GetJsonAsync<IEnumerable<User>>()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```